# Weight of fresh vs frozen tumours

Tags: cancer

I have some mouse tumours that have been snap frozen in liquid nitrogen following an in vivo study, and I thought it might be interesting to also determine the weight of the tumours. I was wondering if weighing frozen tumours would still be accurate, or if I should have measured them before they were frozen? Would one expect the weight to be significantly altered just by snap freezing samples?

Comment: If the tumours were sealed before being frozen, then of course the weight is the same. The temperature of something does not change its mass. However, the frozen ones might be heavier if, during the process, more water (or other substances) got trapped into the tumour. At the end this is a problem of enginneering and about your freezing method and not a question of biology.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question of engineering of the freezing technique and not a question of biology.

Comment: I think this is specific enough to a biological technique that it's on topic.

Comment: I agree with Bryan; closing this question would be failing to see the forest for the trees.